# Should we include TV shows or series in the definition of "idle talk"?

Tags: quran, terminology, tv

The phrase "idle talks" appears in this ayah;

**“And of mankind is he who purchases idle talks (i.e. music, singing) to mislead (men) from the path of Allaah…” [Luqmaan 31:6]**

In an article about music being haram it is mentioned that idle talks are used to distract from the Qur'an and there were people in Makkah telling stories about Roman kings and they were works of kafirs. [Source](https://islamqa.info/en/5000)

So my question is, should we include tv shows or series into this idle talk definition or not?

Comment: Have you read any tafsir before posting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is mainly for the interpretation of an ayah of Quran, so instead of TRYING to interpret it over again myself, i will quote from an already existing tafseer:

[31. Surah Luqman - Sayyid Abul Ala Maududi - Tafhim al-Qur'an - The Meaning of the Qur'an](http://englishtafsir.com/Quran/31/index.html#sdfootnote6sym)

He writes:

> The words **lahv al-hadith in the Text imply such a thing as may allure and absorb a listener completely and make him heedless of
>   everything else around him. Lexically, there is nothing derogatory in
>   these words, but in custom and usage they apply to evil and useless
>   and vain things, such as gossip, nonsensical talk, joking and jesting,
>   legends and tales, singing and merry-making, etc**.
>  "To buy"
>   alluring tales may also mean that the person concerned adopts
>   falsehood instead of the Truth, turns away from the guidance and turns
>   to those things which can neither benefit him in the world nor in the
>   Hereafter. But this is the metaphorical meaning. The real meaning of
>   the sentence is that a person should purchase an absurd and useless
>   thing for his money, and this is supported by many traditions. **Ibn
>   Hisham has related on the authority of Ibn Ishaq that when the
>   disbelievers of Makkah could not stop the message of the Holy Prophet
>   from spreading in spite of their best efforts, Nadr bin Harith said to
>   the people of Quraish: "The way you are counteracting this man will
>   avail you nothing. He has lived a lifetime among you. Until now he was
>   the best of your men morally: he was the most truthful and the most
>   trustworthy person among you. Now you say that he is a sorcerer and
>   enchanter and a poet and a madman. Who will believe all this? Don't
>   the people know the way the sorcerers talk? Don't they know the
>   enchanters and the way they conduct their business? Are they unaware
>   of poetry and of. the states of madness? Which of these accusations
>   sticks to Muhammad (upon whom be Allah's peace) by exploiting which
>   you would turn the people's attention away from him? Look! I will tell
>   you how to deal with him." Then he left Makkah for Iraq and managed to
>   get from there legends and tales about the kings of Iran and Rustam
>   and Isfandyar and started to arrange tale-telling parties to distract
>   the people from the Qur'an and to absorb them in the tales. (Ibn
>   Hisham. vol. I, pp. 320-321)**. The same tradition has been cited by
>   Vahidi in Asbab un Nazul on the authority of Kalbi and Muqatil. And
>   according to Ibn 'Abbas, Nadr had bough singing girls also for the
>   purpose. Whenever he heard that someone was coming under the Holy
>   Prophet's influence, he would impose a singing girl an him with the
>   instruction: "Feed him and entertain him with your songs so that he is
>   absorbed in you and distracted from the other side." This was the same
>   device which the arch-criminals of the nations have been employing in
>   every age. They try to get the common people so absorbed in fun and
>   sport and musical entertainment's in the name of culture that they are
>   left with no time and sense to attend to the serious problems of life,
>   and in their heedlessness they do not even feel what destruction they
>   are being driven to.
>  The same commentary of lahv al-hadith has
>   been reported from a large number of the Companions and their
>   immediate followers. '**Abdullah bin Mas'ud was asked, 'What does lahv
>   al-hadith mean in this verse ?" He said thrice emphatically. 'By God!
>   it means singing." (Ibn Jarir, Ibn Abi Shaibah. Hakim, Baihaqi)**.
>   Similar traditions have been reported from scholars like 'Abdullah
>   bin' Abbas, Jabir bin 'Abdullah, Mujahid, 'Ikrimah, Said bin Jubair,
>   Hasan Basri: and Makhul. Ibn Jarir, Ibn Abi Hatim and Tirmidhi have
>   related on the authority of Hadrat Abu Umamah Baheli that the Holy
>   Prophet said, "It is not lawful to buy and sell and trade in singing
>   girls nor is it lawful to take their price." In another tradition, the
>   last sentence is to the effect: ... it is unlawful to eat their price"
>   . Yet another tradition from Abu Umamah is to the effect: To teach
>   music to slave-girls and to trade in them is not lawful and their
>   price is forbidden." AII these Ahadith also elucidate that the verse
>   containing lahv al-hadith was sent down in this very connection. Qadi
>   Abu Bakr Ibn al-'Arabi has related in the Ahkam alQur'an a Hadith from
>   Hadrat 'Abdullah bin Mubarak and Imam Malik on the authority of Hadrat
>   Anas, saying, that the Holy Prophet said: 'He who hears the song of a
>   singing-girl in a musical concert, will have molten lead poured into
>   his ear on the Day of Judgment" (In this connection, one should also
>   note that the culture" of music in those days flourished almost
>   entirely through the slave-girls: Free women had not yet become
>   "artists" . That is why the Holy Prophet spoke about trading in
>   slave-girls, and described their wages and earnings as their price.
>   and used the word qaynah for the singing-girl, which is specifically
>   used for a slave-girl in Arabic).

So, after reading all this tafsir, coming back to your question, **should we include tv shows or series into this idle talk definition or not?**

I remember once i talked about this with a sheikh and what he said was that **yes this also includes in lahv-al hadis**, not that intensely as of listening to girls singing and music etc. But he told me that these all talk shows which have discussions for hours which are of no use, we leave many important things because of them, sometimes even salaah, we don't read quran and we listen to them, and just to make ratings and make people fight on their shows so their show can get popular, these all kind of things are included in this. **Until or unless those are constructive and about the topics knowing about and discussing about which will benefit you in any way. And you are not missing your salaah etc because of them.** He explained me the detailed meaning of word لھو which i don't remember exactly, but what i remember is that i was convinced.