# Sharing videos in website is halal or haram?

Tags: halal-haram, internet

Assalam-0-Aliakum . I am a Blogger and i want to start a news website where i will provide recent talk shows, debates, and information about Politics. Is sharing such type of content halal or haram ? Of course i will be using adsense to earn from the website.

> Example Website : siasat.pk

Comment: You can search on why making videos(cartoons or of living things) is makrooh (and some ulama still consider it haram, i go with makrooh) and why talkshows etc are discouraged read my answer http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/32689/15642 and than i will advice you to avoid this and go for something better. May allah accept your curiosity.

Comment: sure let me read that and will back to you.